# Python - Edit text to only keep domain names from URLs in given text

Tags: python, regex, url, dns

I've managed to scrape certain website for comments, however it scrapes the HTML and thus have a lot of complete URLs that I want to clean up for NLTK anaylsis, without the constant "https://wwww." messing with the frequency of word results.

For example, if I have this text:

> In the world of selective animal breeding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_breeding), to "breed true" means that specimens of an animal breed will breed true-to-type when mated like-to-like; that is, that the progeny of any two individuals in the same breed will show consistent, replicable and predictable characteristics. A puppy from two purebred dogs of the same breed, for example, will exhibit the traits of its parents, and not the traits of all breeds in the subject breed's ancestry.
>
> However, breeding from too small a gene pool, especially direct inbreeding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbreeding), can lead to the passing on of undesirable characteristics or even a collapse of a breed population due to inbreeding depression. Therefore, there is a question, and often heated controversy, as to when or if a breed may need to allow "outside" stock in for the purpose of improving the overall health and vigor of the breed.
>
> Because pure-breeding creates a limited gene pool, purebred animal breeds are also susceptible to a wide range of congenital health problems.[1] This problem is especially prevalent in competitive dog breeding and dog show circles due to the singular emphasis on aesthetics rather than health or function. Such problems also occur within certain segments of the horse industry for similar reasons. The problem is further compounded when breeders practice

I'd like the URLs in the () to simply be the domain name, in this case (wikipedia). I've played around with regex and found a similar question, however it re.subs the URL (in this case) to (wikipedia.com). I don't want the domain suffix, just the name of the website/domain. So if it's en.wikipedia.com -> wikipedia

The regex code I found is `re.sub('https*://[\w\.]+\.com[\w/\-]+|https*://[\w\.]+\.com|[\w\.]+\.com/[\w/\-]+', lambda x:re.findall('(?<=\://)[\w\.]+\.com|[\w\.]+\.com', x.group())[0], s)`

Answer (score 0):

You would like to use [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module of the standard library (urlparse in python 2).

Once you have the netloc, it is just a matter of removing the port number if any and splitting the domain string on the dots.